# How to install flask on windows

Tags: python, flask

Please tell me how to install flask on windows.

I have tried to install using `pip install` ,but I cannot install flask.

I already tried install flask on windows like this:

```
pip install flask
```

Comment: Have you read [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org)?

Comment: Have you followed the installation instructions? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/installation/#installation

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Could you poste the error here by editing your question and adding it to the end in code formatting?

Comment: There should be no issues installing Flask on Windows, I've done it many times. What was the error?

Comment: I tried flask tutorial print”hello world”

Comment: I tried flask tutorial print”hello world”      Import error: import flask does not defined

Comment: So the _installation_ works fine (finishes successfully), but `from flask import Flask` says it can't find the module? Where are you trying to import the library?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you could try "pip3 install flask"? I'm not sure what version you are using though.

Comment: This looks like a wild guess. Please see [answer].